# Why would JS character limits break in Safari?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, character, character-limit

I'm doing some character limiting on inputs using JS (because there isn't any other way of doing this on Shopify) and it works great in FF & Chrome but in Safari I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.

It refers to the definitions within `form:` below

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var shippingAddressEl = document.querySelector('.section--shipping-address')
if (shippingAddressEl) {
  var formValidation = {
    els: {
      el: shippingAddressEl,
      form: {
        firstname: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][first_name]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        lastname: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][last_name]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        company: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][company]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        addressLine1: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][address1]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        addressLine2: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][address2]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        city: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][city]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        postcode: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][zip]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),
        phone: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][phone]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis in every line:

```
var formValidation = {
  els: {
    el: shippingAddressEl,
    form: {
      firstname: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][first_name]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      lastname: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][last_name]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      company: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][company]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      addressLine1: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][address1]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      addressLine2: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][address2]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      city: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][city]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      postcode: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][zip]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])'),
      phone: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][phone]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"])')
    }
  }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: OMG, its always the simplest of things! Completely missed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I found out why:

You're missing a `)` in pretty much every value inside your `form` object:

`city: shippingAddressEl.querySelector('input[name="checkout[shipping_address][city]"]:not([data-honeypot="true"]'),`

Comment: No, the quotes are not needed to create a JSON. Try `var json = { a: 1, b: 2 }`. It works

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Updated my post. Thanks again.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh that is an *object* - JSON is a string

Comment: OMG, its always the simplest of things! Completely missed it! Thanks!

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I meant that for the `to create a JSON` comment. JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and it's a string type, while `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` is a plain object and **not** JSON.

Comment: @vlaz Ah I see. Sorry.